# IsGestureEnabled is not working in xamarin forms for iOS 16

Tags: xamarin.forms, orientation, landscape, portrait, ios16

I'm changing the orientation(Landscape/Portrait) forcefully for one screen.
For that, I used IsGestureEnabled property.
That property is not working on iOS 16 or above versions.

**CODE:**

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    SetGestureEnabled(true);
    base.OnDisappearing();
}

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    SetGestureEnabled(false);
    base.OnAppearing();
}

private void SetGestureEnabled(bool isSet)
{
    if (Application.Current.MainPage is MasterDetailPage masterDetailPage)
    {
        masterDetailPage.IsGestureEnabled = isSet;
    }
}
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

MasterDetailPage is obsolete. Try using FlyoutPage instead.

FlyoutPage also has **IsGestureEnabled** property which could disable or enable the swipe gesture. The default value is true. you could use almost the same code in your question

```
if (Application.Current.MainPage is FlyoutPage flyoutPage)
{
    flyoutPage.IsGestureEnabled = true;
}
```

For more info, you could refer to [Xamarin.Forms FlyoutPage](https://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/flyoutpage)